# How to draw a paragraph on image file using Pillow Package

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to pillow package and I am trying to draw a text of paragraph which has about 100 words in center alignment, but the text was going outside of the image, how can I manage it, below is the code I tried:

please let me know

thank you

```
def certgenerator(name,course,datetext,cid):
"""function to generate certificate"""
image_source = Image.open(r'/media/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/certgentestroom/certgen-1/originals/empty002.jpg')
spacing = 50
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_source)
x = datetime.now()
msg3  = x.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
font = ImageFont.truetype("/media/xxxxxx/xxxxx/certgentestroom/fonts/ArialBold.ttf", size=60)
draw.multiline_text((750,730), msg3, fill ="black", font = font,spacing = spacing,align="center")
name_width, name_height = draw.textsize(name, font=font)
# draw.text((WIDTH-name_width/2, HEIGHT-name_height/2), name, fill=FONT_COLOR, font=font)
draw.text((750,850), name, fill=FONT_COLOR, font=font)
font = ImageFont.truetype("/media/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/certgentestroom/fonts/ArialBold.ttf", size=60)
name_width, name_height = draw.textsize(course, font=font)
# draw.text((CWIDTH-name_width/2, CHEIGHT-name_height/2), course, fill=FONT_COLOR, font=font)
draw.text((750,1100), course, fill=FONT_COLOR, font=font)
#Date generation module
#draw.multiline_text((2520,2490), msg3, fill ="black", font = font,spacing = spacing,align="center")    
z=1220
x =0
y = len(description)
for i in range(x,y,12):
    x = i
    print("no.of words:",len(description[x:x+12]))
    print (description[x:x+12])
    j = ' '.join(description[x:x+12])
    draw.multiline_text((755,z), j, fill ="black", font = font,spacing = spacing,align="center")
    z=z+80


# font = ImageFont.truetype("/media/mgbhargava/Codegnan/certgentestroom/fonts/arial.ttf", size=30)
# draw.multiline_text((740,1220), decsription, fill ="black", font = font,spacing = spacing,align="center")    
image_source.save( name+".jpg")
print('printing certificate of: '+name)
```

Comment: There are many ways to draw the paragraph so it would fit. You need to decide which one is to implement and then it would become possible to write code that determined how to do it. As it stands, the goal is too vague.

Comment: okay, any reference or examples regarding to it @martineau

Comment: No, don't know of any. You can use the [`getsize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) method of a PIL `ImageFont` to determine the size — width and height — in pixels of a given text string. The built-in [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module can split the words in a given paragraph into lines with different maximum number of characters in them. I think it should be possible to do what you want using those two functions/methods, but there's lots of moving parts…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, got it i tried to print paragraph on empty background and rendered on required image ,thanks for help